# Issue running with Angular Meteor 1.4.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Hi! I'm trying to install Meteor w/angular flavor, but when i try to install angular project, processing 'stalls' in loop like:

I posted my question at GitList:
https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/1461

#### When reporting a bug, please be sure to include the following:

- [ ] I'm running  Meteor 1.4.1.3. version of `angular-meteor` 
  mongo      upgraded from 1.1.12_5 to 1.1.13
  npm-mongo  upgraded from 2.2.10_1 to 2.2.11_1
  meteor-angular-socially-master: updated to Meteor 1.4.1.3.
- [ ] What packages or other dependencies I'm using
- [ ] The behavior you expect to see, and the actual behavior

I expected angular-meteor to run, and it shows localhost:3000 but it does not show me anything after that.
I have troubled running angular-meteor at my environment.
I git clone the project.

Unable to resolve some modules:

> "@angular/core" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/imports/ui/filters/uninvitedPipe.js (web.browser)
>     "@angular/platform-browser" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/client/main.js (web.browser)
>     "@angular/forms" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/client/main.js (web.browser)
>     "@angular/upgrade" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/client/main.js (web.browser)
>     "@angular/material" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/client/main.js (web.browser)
>     "ng-img-crop/compile/minified/ng-img-crop" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/imports/ui/components/partyUpload/partyUpload.js (web.browser)
>     "ng-img-crop/compile/minified/ng-img-crop.css" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/imports/ui/components/partyUpload/partyUpload.js (web.browser)
>     "stream" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js (web.browser)
>     "events" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/node_modules/gm/index.js (web.browser)
>     "util" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/node_modules/lru-cache/lib/lru-cache.js (web.browser)
>     "fs" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/node_modules/which/which.js (web.browser)
>     "child_process" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js (web.browser)
>     "path" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/node_modules/which/which.js (web.browser)
>     "spawn-sync" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js (web.browser)
>     "angular2-meteor" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/imports/ui/components/partyUninvited/partyUninvited.js (web.browser)
>     "angular-material" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/imports/ui/components/socially/socially.js (web.browser)
>     "angular-sanitize" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/imports/ui/components/socially/socially.js (web.browser)
>     "ionic-sdk/release/js/ionic" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/imports/ui/components/socially/socially.js (web.browser)
>     "ionic-sdk/release/js/ionic-angular" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/imports/ui/components/socially/socially.js (web.browser)
>     "ionic-sdk/release/css/ionic.css" in /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/imports/ui/components/socially/socially.js (web.browser)

If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

> meteor npm install --save @angular ng-img-crop meteor-node-stubs spawn-sync angular2-meteor angular-material angular-sanitize ionic-sdk

npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/@angular
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/jchiu/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2.zi1w5b++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node" "/Users/jchiu/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2.zi1w5b++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "@angular" "ng-img-crop" "meteor-node-stubs" "spawn-sync" "angular2-meteor" "angular-material" "angular-sanitize" "ionic-sdk"
npm ERR! node v4.6.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! path /Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/@angular
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/@angular'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jchiu/Downloads/meteor-angular-socially-master/@angular'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

W20161027-11:35:50.089(-7)? (STDERR) ufs: permissions are not defined for store "thumbs"
W20161027-11:35:50.259(-7)? (STDERR) ufs: permissions are not defined for store "images"
=> Started your app.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the problem.

The error is caused my local node version is very old! 
It's probably v0.10.0 or lower, then again it's important to note all possible information. As I can see in the following piece of spawn-cross https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-cross-spawn/blob/master/index.js#L34 you will need to run the following:

```
$ meteor npm install --save spawn-sync
```

Which is the obvious solution, but I'd recommend to just upgrade the node's version using npm.